# Decoding JSON with JSONKit gives error

Tags: iphone, json

I have the following JSON that validates as valid JSON..

```
{"flights":[{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW699","timestamp":"2011-03-22 07:06:02","route":"LOWW-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW706","timestamp":"2011-03-21 19:08:02","route":"EGLL-LOWW"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW5MG","timestamp":"2011-03-21 16:33:02","route":"LEMG-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW3AG","timestamp":"2011-03-21 11:25:02","route":"EGLL-LEMG"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW5EB","timestamp":"2011-03-20 19:18:02","route":"EGLL-LPPT"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BA0489","timestamp":"2011-03-20 09:40:02","route":"LEBL-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BA0475","timestamp":"2011-03-19 16:51:02","route":"LEBL-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW489","timestamp":"2011-03-18 08:08:02","route":"LEBL-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BA0799","timestamp":"2011-03-17 18:37:02","route":"EGLL>EFHK"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW799","timestamp":"2011-03-17 16:31:01","route":"EFHK-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW794","timestamp":"2011-03-17 11:55:02","route":"EGLL-EFHK"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"GEUUZ","timestamp":"2011-03-17 09:43:02","route":""}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW487","timestamp":"2011-03-16 19:32:01","route":"LEBL-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW486","timestamp":"2011-03-16 16:57:02","route":"EGLL-LEBL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW459","timestamp":"2011-03-16 14:10:01","route":"LEMD-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW41LM","timestamp":"2011-03-16 10:09:02","route":"EGLL-LEMD"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BA0795","timestamp":"2011-03-16 08:27:02","route":""}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW795","timestamp":"2011-03-16 07:01:02","route":"EFHK-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW798","timestamp":"2011-03-15 18:23:02","route":"EGLL-EFHK"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW701","timestamp":"2011-03-15 14:24:01","route":"LOWW-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW700","timestamp":"2011-03-15 11:04:01","route":"EGLL-LOWW"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW68BL","timestamp":"2011-03-15 08:14:01","route":"LEBL-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW82BL","timestamp":"2011-03-14 18:40:03","route":"EGLL-LEBL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW849","timestamp":"2011-03-14 08:15:02","route":"EPWA-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW40CB","timestamp":"2011-03-13 19:30:03","route":"EGLL-LEBL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW475","timestamp":"2011-03-13 15:30:02","route":"LEBL-EGLL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"z.NO-FLIGHTNO","timestamp":"2011-03-13 13:00:03","route":""}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW474","timestamp":"2011-03-13 12:00:03","route":"EGLL-LEBL"}},{"flight":{"flightno":"BAW4WP","timestamp":"2011-03-13 08:45:02","route":"LPPT-EGLL"}}]}
```

I then try and parse this using JSONKit but can only get as far down as "flights"  I cannot seem to access the "flight" object.

When I do the following

```
    -(void)parseJSON:(NSString *)jsonData{

   NSDictionary *deserializedData = [jsonData objectFromJSONString];
    for (id key in deserializedData) {

        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [deserializedData objectForKey:key]);

    }

}
```

Only the following is put out to the log....

```
key: flights, value: (
        {
        flight =         {
            flightno = BAW906N;
            route = "EGLL-EDDF";
            timestamp = "2011-03-24 08:38:02";
        };
    },
        {
        flight =         {
            flightno = BAW365;
            route = "LFLL-EGLL";
            timestamp = "2011-03-24 06:17:01";
        };
    },
        {
        flight =         {
etc....
```

I want to be able to get down to each flight and at the moment am stuck!

Comment: i suggest using json-framework. http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get an array of all flights like this:

```
NSArray *flights = [deserializedData valueForKeyPath:@"flights.flight"];
```

Comment: And is each one a dictionary?

Comment: From the JSON structure, I'd say yes

Answer (score 1):

thats because you have an array of dictionairies in your dictionairy object, acces them like this:

```
for (NSDictionairy *flight in [deserializedData objectForKey:@"flights"]){
    NSLog(@"flight object with route.: %@", [flight objectForKey:@"route"]);
}
```

Comment: Hmm not quite?  Comes up with a lot of errors.  -[NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x719d930 on the NSLog!

Comment: used the wrong variable in the for statement, i editted my code and tested it. works fine.